# table UserAndPlace_userprofile has no column named gender

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-syncdb, syncdb

While I save **UserProfile** into a database,

there's an error **"UserProfile has no column named gender error".**

Here's my models.py

```
 """ UserProfile : user information """
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
     # User basic inherits : username, password, email
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     # Profile information
     nickname = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True, null=False)
     url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
     birth = models.DateField(null=True) # TODO change null = false
     gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
     nation = models.CharField(max_length=63, null=True)
     region = models.CharField(max_length=63, null=True)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     # ImageField: http://goo.gl/ZQEG4e
     avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='/avatar/')
     # Foreign Keys
     tag = models.ManyToManyField(TagCloud)
```

and while I tested it from **./python models.py shell** I typed

```
 > from UserAndPlace.models import *
 > u1 = User.objects.get(username="user1")
 > u1.username
   u'user1'
 > p1 = UserProfile(user=u1, gender="female")
 > p1.user.username
   u'user1'
 > p1.gender
   u'female'
 > p1.save()


 OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-9-e08e160cd285> in <module>()
 ----> 1 p1.save()
 ....
 OperationalError: table UserAndPlace_userprofile has no column named gender
```

I did **python manage.py syncdb** and also check errors with **python manage.py sql UserAndPlace**

How can I fix this errors?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syncdb` will not create or modify columns if they already exist in the database. If you already had the model and then you added the gender column, running `syncdb` will not do anything.

You need to drop the table and re-create it again. If you are using sqlite, simply delete the database file and run syncdb.

If you are using another database, run `manage.py sqlclear yourapp` and this will give you the SQL you need to execute to reset the tables for the app `yourapp` (make sure you replace yourapp with the name of the application that has the profile model).

Then, run syncdb again to recreate your models.

Comment: I already drop my table using 'sqlclear' but occurred same error. Anything else I do, sir?

Comment: Just typing it will not clear it, you need to execute it. Try `python manage.py dbshell < python manage.py sqlclear yourapp`, then run `python manage.py syncdb` and if you are using south, `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `python manage.py syncdb` after you made any changes to your model? This error usually happens when the model and the database are out of sync.